# Clearing an optional argument at each call

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, recursion

How would you define a function that takes an optional argument and appends to it without having to provide the argument? The code is something like

```
def myfunc(value, values=[]):
    values.append(value)
    return values

print(myfunc("item"))
print(myfunc("item"))
```

expected output would be

```
['item']
['item']
```

instead of

```
['item']
['item', 'item']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using mutable (dicts, lists etc) as default arguments.

Instead you can do the following.

```
def myfunc(value, values=None):
    if values is None:
        values = []
    values.append(value)
    return values

print(myfunc("item"))
print(myfunc("item"))
```